# Keeping punctuation as its own unit in Preprocessed Text

Tags: python, text, punctuation

what is the code to split a sentence into a list of its constituent words AND punctuation? Most text preprocessing programs tend to remove punctuations.

For example, if I enter this:

> ```
> "Punctuations to be included as its own unit."
> ```

The desired output would be:

> result = ['Punctuations', 'to', 'be', 'included', 'as', 'its', 'own',
> 'unit', '.']

many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to consider using a Natural Language Toolkit or `nltk`.

Try this:

```
import nltk

sentence = "Punctuations to be included as its own unit."
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
print(tokens)
```

Output: `['Punctuations', 'to', 'be', 'included', 'as', 'its', 'own', 'unit', '.']`

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet can be used using regular expression to separate the words and punctuation in a list.

```
import string
import re

punctuations = string.punctuation
regularExpression="[\w]+|" + "[" + punctuations + "]"

content="Punctuations to be included as its own unit."
splittedWords_Puncs = re.findall(r""+regularExpression, content)
print(splittedWords_Puncs)
```

Output: ['Punctuations', 'to', 'be', 'included', 'as', 'its', 'own', 'unit', '.']

Comment: You realize that this `punctuationList = "[" + string.punctuation + "]"` *does not* create a list?

Comment: In regular expression definition, it should be defined as a list inside a string like "[.,;?......]" . Due to this formatting, I used the specified way.

Comment: `the opening square bracket [` in Regex is *not* a list but a *metacharacter*. And what you're effectively passing there is a `string`. Read more on Regex here - https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html

Comment: I understand your point. Thank you. But I think, my code snippet works, doesn't it?